# Variables bounds not taken into account by Z3 / OCaml binding

Tags: neural-network, ocaml, z3

Good afternoon,

I am trying to build a formula with some variables that have bounds, using the Z3 OCaml bindings. For the context, I am trying to prove safety properties on a neural network encoded as an SMT formula.

Some of my inputs variables have bounds on their values, bounds that I would like to
add as constraints on my SMT formulaes. I am then iteratively adding new constraints to my solver stack and checking if they are working.

Here is the initial content of the solver stack, obtained with `Z3.Solver.get_assertions`. It contains the neural network control flow without certain
nodes, the weights and biases values, and the input bound constraints.

```
(forall ((x Real)) (= (reluR x) (ite (> x 0.0) x 0.0)))
[...]
;bunch of variables definitions and constraints
[...]
;input variables definitions
(> |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| (/ 1.0 2.0))
(< |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| 2.0)
(> |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| (/ 1.0 2.0))
(< |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| 2.0)
;a bunch of contraints defining the control flow of the network, here is an example
(= |CELL_actual_output_0_0_0_0| (+ |CELL_22_0_0_0_0| |CELL_l_4.bias_0|))
(= |CELL_14_0_0_0_1|
   (+ (* |CELL_12_0_0_0_0| |CELL_25_0_1|)
      (* |CELL_12_0_0_0_1| |CELL_25_1_1|)
      (* |CELL_12_0_0_0_2| |CELL_25_2_1|)
      (* |CELL_12_0_0_0_3| |CELL_25_3_1|)))
[...]
```

I then added the following expressions, describing the activation of a ReLU node.

```
(= |CELL_20_0_0_0_0| |CELL_19_0_0_0_0|)
(> |CELL_19_0_0_0_0| 0.0)
```

The solver answer positively, and something bugs me on the corresponding model:

```
[...]
(define-fun |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| () Real
  0.0)
(define-fun |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| () Real
  0.0)
[...]
```

It seems that it violates my input bounds constraints.

The content of solver stack after solving is the following, I am not sure I am understanding the lines from the forall

```
(forall ((x Real)) (= (reluR x) (k!11 x)))
(not (<= |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1| (/ 1.0 2.0)))
(not (<= 2.0 |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_1|))
(not (<= |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0| (/ 1.0 2.0)))
(not (<= 2.0 |CELL_actual_input_0_0_0_0|))
(forall ((x!1 Real))
  (! (or (not (<= x!1 0.0)) (= (k!11 x!1) 0.0)) :pattern ((k!11 x!1))))
(forall ((x!1 Real))
  (! (or (<= x!1 0.0) (= (k!11 x!1) x!1)) :pattern ((k!11 x!1))))
```

Note that I am declaring my control flow where the inputs variables are already appearing first, then I redeclare my input with the `Arithmetic.Real.mk_const_s ctx name`, where
`name` is the same. Could it be that the variable being recorded twice in the stack?

Thank in advance for your answers

Comment: Yes, `mk_const*` will always create a new const of your chosen name. The name does not matter to Z3 in any way; you can create as many consts with the same name as you like.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. But then how can I create a bound constraint on a constant that already exists?

Comment: Usually you would remember the object when you create it (at the call to `mk_const*`). If, in your application, you're sure that symbol names won't be reused, that can be a simple lookup table. In theory, you could also run over all the existing constraints and find the object you're looking for, but that's a bit slow.

Comment: Alright, so the simplest way would be to have some lookup table storing all my constants in my applications (names are quite important for what I am trying to achieve). Thanks for taking the time to clarify this :)